# Compress/Resize jpeg and get the Base64 in Javascript

Tags: javascript, resize, compression, base64, image-resizing

How to reduce the size of a base64 String for a Jpeg Image?
I have the base64 of a 2000x1000px photo.
How to get the 500x250px base64 compressed photo?
Someone can help me?

Comment: use it's data url to load it as an image, render it (resized) to a canvas element, store the result from `toDataURL`.

Answer (score 6):

put the base64 in an image tag

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "data:image/gif;base64," + yourBase64;
```

draw it to a scaled canvas

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = img.width;
canvas.height = img.height;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.scale(0.25, 0.25);
ctx.drawImage(img);
```

get the base64

```
var base64 = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
```

I didn't actually test this so the resizing part might be wrong,
but it would be something like this.

try searching how to resize images using the canvas tag.